# how to force layout ar to read device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm using shared preferences to force layout-ar to work

it works fine with emulator but in my read device it did not working ,

i'm sure Arabic set local it calling and getLocal() it returns Arabic , but my layout not going to layout-ar

```
protected static void setLocale(final Context ctx, final String lang) {
    final Locale loc = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(loc);
    final Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.locale = loc;
    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(cfg, null);
}
```

Comment: do you call setLocale before you inflate your layout?

Comment: yes it set it in splash screen sometime working and sometime not working , maybe i should to invalidate setContentView ?